# Code Snippet Completion Action VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

In VS 2010, I could type `prop` and hit tab twice and it automatically inserted a property skeleton for me to complete. I recently switched to VS 2012, and now it only requires pressing tab once, and I find myself constantly having to shift-tab to return back to the return type.

Is there a way to change it back to two tabs? I have ReSharper, if that matters (had it in 2010, too).

Comment: It looks as if ReSharper 'prop' live template is inserted in this case. Please disable ReSharper here Tools | Options | ReSharper | Suspend Now and check the behavior once again.

Comment: @Alexander That was it. It turns out that what I actually want is ReSharper Intellisense in general, but with VS code snippets (or at least the prop snippet). Unfortunately, from what I can tell, this is not currently possible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is ReSharper, and changing this functionality is not currently possible. I can get the old completion behavior back, but it requires disabling ReSharper Intellisense entirely, and going back to VS Intellisense.